# Auto-text Chrome extension: what happened to "Welcome to Stack Overflow"?

Tags: discussion, bug, comments

I am using said Chrome extension, and I just saw that it produces

> "Welcome to Where Developers Learn, Share, & Build Careers! my text ..."

all of a sudden.

Earlier on, it would print "Welcome to Stack Overflow" when auto-texting to newbie users.

I honestly prefer the old way.

Any idea where/how to fix this?

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/79894844) for an example. The auto add generated:

> Welcome to Where Developers Learn, Share, & Build Careers! Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example. Use the "edit" link to improve your question - do not add more information via comments. Thanks!

The "info" link on the Chrome extension points [here](https://github.com/Benjol/SE-AutoReviewComments). The version is 1.4.3. Maybe important or not: this is a "brand new" installation. I can't say for sure if I saw "Welcome to Stack Overflow" on this new machine.

Comment: It is [AutoReviewComments - Pro-forma comments for SE](https://stackapps.com/questions/2116/autoreviewcomments-pro-forma-comments-for-se) what you use, right?

Comment: @rene Once it aint my fault. But I digress. Yes, you are correct.

Comment: Looks like a possible bug. See https://github.com/Benjol/SE-AutoReviewComments/blob/master/src/autoreviewcomments.user.js#L26, it assumes a certain title format.

Comment: @Stijn so far the html looks fine for me, I checked a few pages but I only get the sitename there, not the pay-off.

Comment: Shouldn't this be on [Stack Apps](https://stackapps.com/)?

Comment: Specifically, [Auto Review Comments in stackapps](https://stackapps.com/questions/2116/autoreviewcomments-pro-forma-comments-for-se).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure where you picked that strange sitename up but for now can you go into the Developer Tools of Chrome, visit the Application tab, click Local Storage at the left and find and select the entry `autoreviewcomments-WelcomeMessage`. In the top bar you can then click on the cross to delete the selected entry. Refresh after you clicked as the list won't refresh automagically.

That should reset the message and fetch it again from a Stack Overflow page. Make sure your first fetch is on a Question page and not on the tour or help center or so.

An image for guidance:

[image]

If you go *huh, why do I need to fiddle with stuff under the hood* you might like @Mayken's suggestion and use the [built-in UI instead](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UUPiy.png).

Thanks to [Stijn](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/357195/auto-text-chrome-extension-what-happened-to-welcome-to-stackoverflow/357201#comment518085_357195) for digging up the code that made this go wrong in the first place.

Comment: Just FYI: You can also edit the welcome message for the site you are on through the auto-comment UI. You can do this through the ["welcome" button at the right of the list buttons along the bottom of the UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UUPiy.png). However, the issue is broader than just the Welcome message. It affects anywhere the `$SITENAME$` variable is substituted, which can affect the body of comments.

Comment: Thanks, that worked. And seriously: thanks for putting up that screenshot - it still took me several minutes to find the correct spot.